# Spring boot how to evaluate property with square brackets [a,b,c]

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am using spring-boot-1.5.19 and in my application.yml I have below the entry

```
sample:
  image:
    size-array: [280, 420, 560, 840, 1120]
```

I used below code to access the above property

```
@Value("#{'${sample.image.size-array}'.split(',')}")
public List<Integer> sizes;
```

But I was getting error then used below style,

```
@Value("#{sample.image.size-array}")
public List<Integer> sizes;
```

Also, I Tried with string but no luck. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Any specific reason you have the sq brackets ?

Comment: In case of a comma separated elements like :
size-array=280, 420, 560, 840, 1120, if I inject "${size-array}" to a List<Integer> list, the list becomes = [280, 420, ...].......... So I do not see the use of brackets.

Comment: I know how to parse with our square bracket but this is how they designed so I cannot change the structure

Comment: So you saying, in your properties file, the string [280,.......] is fixed and can't be changed ? Did I understand you correctly ?

Comment: Yes it is fixed

Comment: Posted an expression which works, but still I am so uncomfortable writing this expression :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below Spel Exp for parsing the data into a list:

```
@Value("#{'${sample.image.size-array}'.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split(',')}")
    private List<Integer> sizes ;
```

Comment: It is not working. Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'sample.image.size-array' in value "#{'${sample.image.size-array}'.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split(',')}"

Comment: Works fine with .properties file. This must be an issue/something wrong what we are doing with @Value injection from yml, I am reading other links from StackOverflow, in case you find something drop a link too. Thanks

Comment: Add this to the config class/Springboot bootstrap class :
@PropertySource("classpath:application.yml")

This is worked for me, but I am still confused about why I need to do this